# Where can I find Arabic Quran recitation resources such as audio without Tajweed?

Tags: quran, quran-recitation, tajweed

I'm looking for a Quran recitation (mp3, video, application, website, ...) in Arabic which is just a simple reading of the verses without Tajweed enhancement.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. What do you mean by without tajweed? I mean most of the Quran recitation you'll find on the net are without tajweed unless it is special quoted. As many recitation are just records from taraweh prayers. If i get you right you mean you want a Quran reading (without use of any rules of tajweed), is that correct?

Comment: Yes, a Quran reading without the use of rules, just a simple reading of the Quran

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your question is that scholars say it's not allowed to recite the Quran without at least "the odor" of tajweed, so it's not allowed to read it as you would read any text. This applies especially for somebody who know it based on verse ([73:4](http://legacy.quran.com/73/4))!

> Or add to it, and recite the Qur'an with measured recitation.

Note that Quran has been revealed as "mujawad" and therefore transmitted the same why!
So one is asked to learn at least tajweed of surat al-Fatiha and or do his best to learn the rules step by step. On the other hands Maliki scholars who take the -supposed- teachings of Imam Malik literally would fit. Most Imams in Morocco used to recite in such a style (with a slight application of the tajweed rules and in a neutral theme) when i was a child, but now some adapted the middle-eastern customs and teachings. But they would recite in riwayat warsh 'an Nafi' not the common and wide spread riway of Hafs 'an 'Assim.

Answer (score 1):

Please check these mobile apps:

[android version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alisons.quranfirst&hl=en) &
[ios version](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/quran-first/id900910193?mt=8)

Note: It has Quran Arabic text, Translations, Transliteration,audio & Thajweed mark plus lot of functionalities.

Answer (score -1):

You can find Ayat - Al-Qur'an on [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sa.edu.ksu.Ayat&hl=in) or [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ayat-al.../id634325420?mt=8)